# Parsing data from js variable containing html

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is snippet of `html` that I will be parsing. It is stored inside a `js` variable.

```
<tr class='preview'>
    <td class='statistics show' title='Show latest match stats'>
        <button class="js-hide">Show</button>
    </td>

    <td class='match-details'>
        <p>
            <span class='team-home teams'>
                <a href='#'>Leicester</a>
            </span>
            <span class='versus'>
                <abbr title='Versus'> V </abbr> 
            </span>                  
            <span class='team-away teams'>
                <a href='#'>Crystal Palace</a>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>

    <td class='kickoff'>
        15:00
    </td>
    <td class='status'></td>
</tr>
<tr class='preview'>
    <td class='statistics show' title='Show latest match stats'>
        <button class="js-hide">Show</button>
    </td>

    <td class='match-details'>
        <p>
            <span class='team-home teams'>
                <a href='#'>Liverpool</a>
            </span>
            <span class='versus'>
                <abbr title='Versus'> V </abbr> 
            </span>                  
            <span class='team-away teams'>
                <a href='#'>Spurs</a>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>

    <td class='kickoff'>
        15:00
    </td>
    <td class='status'></td>
</tr>
```

Result ..

```
Leicester vs. Crystal Palace
Liverpool vs. Spurs
```

I'm interested in the `home` and `away` team names. The `vs.` can be added between each easily.

Could anyone suggest if there is a simple solution for parsing this `string`? Are `RegEx` the only approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) with its `parseFromString` method.

Simply pass in your HTML string (and a specified mime-type like `'text/html'`) into the parser, and you'll get a `Document` object (or `HTMLDocument`, to be specific, if you specify the type as `'text/html'`).

With this `Document`, you can then query it as usual (whether with `querySelector`, `getElement*`, or a library like jQuery).

Here's an example:

```
var parsedHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHTMLVariable, 'text/html');
var teams = parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('.teams');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the HTML string into a temporary element and query it using DOM methods. For example

```
// HTML in "html" variable

var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = html;

var homeTeams = tmp.querySelectorAll('.team-home');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(homeTeams, function(team) {
    console.log(team.textContent);
});
```